# How to use different meta details for English frontpage

Tags: views, theming, 7

I have set up a multilingual website using D7.
Now I have two front pages:

1. Chinese
2. and English.

I have added meta info for front pages in:

```
Configuration -> Search and Metadata -> Meta Tags
```

But the same meta is coming for both Chinese and English. I need separate metadata for both.

Is it possible?

Thanks